# Debug Bot Framework Composer with Visual Studio Code

Tags: botframework

I would like to run the [Microsoft Bot Framework Composer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer) on my local machine in Chrome as a web application with debug configuration and attach Visual Studio Code's debugger to it to debug the changes I've made to the code. What is the best way of doing that?

I know that I can run the application locally with these steps (from the official README):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer.git
$ cd BotFramework-Composer
$ cd Composer // switch to Composer folder
$ yarn install // install dependencies
$ yarn build // build extensions and libs
$ yarn startall // start client and server at the same time
```

But as I see, this is starting the app with production configuration, so attaching a debugger to it wouldn't make too much sense. I think there must be an easy, pre-configured way of doing this (I mean the dev team must be doing this pretty often :)), I just struggle to find it in the official repository.